# Swagger-UI Customization

Tags: swagger, swagger-ui

I am using [Swagger-UI 2.2.10](https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-ui/tree/v2.2.10) I want to customize some messages but could not find the exact place in the **/src/main** folder. Can some one point out the place from where Swagger-UI is fetching this message, Screenshot is attached.
[image]
I want to chnage this message in swagger-UI.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Swagger UI 2.x, these messages live in https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-ui/tree/2.x/lang. There are separate files for different languages.

Comment: do i have your contact email or SkypeId? because you have good concepts of swagger which will be very helpful for me.

Comment: No, sorry. You can ask questions here so that other people can help and future readers can benefit from the info.